# Dependency between Map key and value type parameters in Scala

Tags: scala, types, dictionary, existential-type, parametric-polymorphism

Sometimes it may be useful to encode dependency between types of keys and values in a map. Consider the following type:

```
type MyPairs = Seq[(TypeTag[T], T) forSome {type T}]
```

Here each pair in the sequence should have the same type `T`. But such type is not very convenient in terms of map-like usage. However I cannot express such dependency for `Map[K, V]`, because `Map` has two independent type parameters, and it seems I cannot "group" them in any way to use single existential type. Naive variant

```
type MyMap = Map[TypeTag[T], T] forSome {type T}
```

just forces the single type `T`. for all `MyMap` entries, but not for each one of them individually.

Another extreme, I believe, is

```
type MyMap = Map[TypeTag[_], _]
```

But this is, of course, too broad definition which allows any combination of key-value types.

So my question is, it is possible to encode such type in Scala? If yes, how?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401329/map-from-classtto-t-without-casting ; also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038708/scala-existential-types-for-a-map

Comment: @0__, thank you. It seems that my searching skills are somewhat lacking...

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, you need to use a heterogenous map.  The shapeless project has an implementation of this:

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-1.2.4#heterogenous-maps

This allows you to do:

```
import shapeless._
class Constrainer[K, V]
implicit def allowed[T] = new Constrainer[Class[T], T]
val hmap = HMap[Constrainer](classOf[String] -> "Hi there", classOf[Int] -> 3) // this compiles
val hmapFail = HMap[Constrainer](classOf[String] -> 3) // this won't compile
```

For your specific example using TypeTag's:

```
import shapeless._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
class Constrainer[K, V]
implicit def allowed[T] = new Constrainer[TypeTag[T], T]
val hmap = HMap[Constrainer](typeTag[String] -> "hello", typeTag[Int] -> 2) // this compiles
val hmapFail = HMap[Constrainer](typeTag[String] -> 3) // this won't compile
```

Notice that you can use an implicit value (or conversion as in our case) to dictate what instances of (key, value) pairs are allowed.