# Scala list of any and list of something extending Any. What is a difference?

Tags: scala, generics, existential-type

Could anyone explain what is difference between:
`Seq[Any]` and `Seq[_ <: Any]` ?
To my eye, I can put everything in both cases as everything extends `Any`.

Comment: `Any` is a symptom of bad design

Comment: @user You can. Try it: `val seq1: Seq[_ <: Any] = Seq(1, 2, 3); val seq2 = seq1 :+ ""`.

Comment: @cchantep Generally yes, but for covariant `F`, `F[Any]` is the same as existential type `F[_]` and existential types are not necessarily a symptom of bad design :)

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Huh, that's weird. I guess I was thinking about Java's wildcards.

Comment: @cchantep The same question with the same answer could be asked about `Seq[_ <: SomeType]` and `Seq[SomeType]`.

Comment: @user The difference is not because of existential types vs wildcards, but because of different signatures of `:+` (and similar Scala methods) and mutating `add` in Java.

Comment: What is difference between extensial and wildcard?

Comment: @tomek.xyz In Scala 2 there are existential types that are not wildcarded https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447779/underscore-for-existential-type-in-scala https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038708/scala-existential-types-for-a-map https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61701021/understanding-type-arguments-do-not-conform-to-class-type-parameter-bounds-error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61215541/self-type-annotation-for-class-with-higher-kinded-type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61041172/is-there-a-shorthand-for-type-variable-m-forsome-type-mo-upperboundo

Comment: @tomek.xyz For example `Foo[Bar[_]]` aka `Foo[Bar[X] forSome {type X}]` is wildcarded but `Foo[Bar[X]] forSome {type X}` is not.

Comment: I don't think this is a JVM question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here there's no difference because [`Seq` is covariant](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html). So:

1. `Seq[Any]` is a subtype of `Seq[_ <: Any]` because that `_` could be `Any`;
2. `Seq[_ <: Any]` is a subtype of `Seq[Any]` because whatever you put instead of `_` you'll get a subtype of `Seq[Any]`.

If you replace `Seq` by some invariant `F` (e.g. `Set`), `Set[Any]` is a subtype of `Set[_ <: Any]` but not vice versa. `Set[_ <: Any]` is the common supertype of `Set[Any]`, `Set[String]`, `Set[Int]` etc.

In more detail:

1. `Set[_ <: Any]` is a shorthand for `Set[T] forSome { T <: Any }`.
2. `Set[T] forSome { T <: Any }` is the supertype of all `Set[T]` for types `T` which satisfy `T <: Any`. The specification [says](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#existential-types)

   > The set of values denoted by the existential type `T forSome {Q}` is the union of the set of values of all its type instances.

   but that's the same thing.

So code like

```
val set1: Set[String] = ??? 
val set2: Set[_ <: Any] = set1
```

will compile (try it!). And it still will if you replace `String` by any other type (`_ <: ...` is not a type). But

```
val set1: Set[String] = ??? 
val set2: Set[Any] = set1
```

won't.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let's consider `java.util.map<K,V>`I understand that in case of such map I should use: `java.util.map<String, _ <: Any>` instead of `java.util.map<String, Any>` ?

Comment: And second question: `but not vice versa.` Why? After all, everything extends (is) scala is `Any`

Comment: "I understand that in case of such map I should use" It very much depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: "Why? After all, everything extends (is) scala is Any". Because e.g. `Set[String]` is not a subtype of `Set[Any]`. And `Set[_ <: Any]` is the common supertype of `Set[Any]`, `Set[String]`, `Set[Int]` etc.

Comment: After all, `Set` is invariant so there is no relation: `if A extends B then Set[A] extends Set[B]` (such relation is about covariantion). Hence, why do you claim that `Set[_ <: Any]` is supertype of `Set[String]` ? It should *not* be result of relation `String extends Any`

Comment: "so there is no relation: if A extends B then Set[A] extends Set[B]". Right. In particular, `Set[String]` doesn't extend `Set[Any]`. But it doesn't say anything about `Set[_ <: Any]`.

Comment: I've extended the answer with a demonstration.

Comment: @tomek.xyz `Foo[_ <: Bar]` is a supertype of all `Foo[X]` (`X <: Bar`) and moreover it's the minimal such supertype.

Comment: Does it mean that syntax `_ <: Bar` forces covariance on type `Bar`. In other words for every `Foo` extending `Bar` `Set[Foo] extends Set[Bar]`. Yeah?

Comment: No, it extends `Set[_ <: Bar]`, _not_ `Set[Bar]`.

Comment: However, effect is the same. It works like it would extends `Set[Bar]`

Comment: @tomek.xyz `_ <: A`, `_ >: A` are ways to transform invariant types into co/contravariant: `type Foo[A]` `type CoFoo[+A] = Foo[_ <: A]` `type ContraFoo[-A] = Foo[_ >: A]`. But `Foo` is still invariant.

Answer (score 3):

I'll just add to **@AlexeyRomanov**'s answer a quote of specific place in Scala spec:

> 3.2.12 Existential Types
>
> Simplification Rules
>
> 4.An existential type  `forSome {  }` where  contains a clause type `[tps]>:<:` is equivalent to the type `′ forSome {  }` where `′` results from  by replacing every *covariant*
> occurrence of  in  by  and by replacing every
> contravariant occurrence of  in  by .

https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#simplification-rules

`Seq[_ <: Any]` is `Seq[T] forSome { type T <: Any}`, the occurrence of `T` in `Seq[T]` is covariant because `Seq` is covariant, so `Seq[T] forSome { type T <: Any} =:= Seq[Any] forSome { type T <: Any} =:= Seq[Any]` (the last step also uses simplification rule #2).

Comment: Strictly speaking this rule only gives you `Seq[Any] forSome { type T <: Any }`. You need to include the "Unused quantifications can be dropped" part as well.